# Desktop Converter app failed in store submission

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-store

I just got a certification report for my recent submission and it contains this claim:

```
App Policies: 10.3.1 App Is Not Testable
Notes To Developer
    Your app doesn’t install on one or more of your currently selected device families. Please check that your device family selection is correct and re-submit your app.

Does not install on: desktop

Tested Devices: Windows 10 Desktop
```

Can any one suggest me for this. I have created the bundle using Desktop app converter.

I checked this previous post:
[App is not testable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738593/app-is-not-testable).

But still my issue not solved, still I am getting the same error, I am not getting any much details about the app failure.

I have created the bundle using this following command

```
makeappx pack -d "C:\Output\MyApp\PackageFiles" -p "C:\Output\MyApp\MyAppfile.appx"
```

and signed using

```
signtool.exe sign /a /v /fd SHA256 /f "C:\Output\MyApp\auto-generated.pfx" /p "123456" "C:\Output\MyApp\MyAppfile.appx"
```

and with this appx, I copy the appx in a separate folder and created the bundle

```
makeappx bundle /p c:\myappfile.appxbundle /d C:\Output\mypackapp
```

mypackapp directory contains the appx file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App is not testable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738593/app-is-not-testable)

Comment: Can you show steps how you created app package, it should contain x86 version for testing in desktop or may be app is crashing on desktop, if you creating mobile specific app dont tick desktop on store

Comment: What device families did you allow for your app? Did you include Mobile or Xbox?

Comment: Allow only for the desktop device

Comment: Have you sideloaded your package on local device? How do you generate a bundle package file? For desktop bridge app, you only need to upload the x86 build for Store submission.

Comment: I have sideloaded local device it was working fine,  I have uploaded the appx file created using Desktop App Converter, can you provide me command to create bundle with this appx file.

Comment: Can any one please help me to publish app in store?

Comment: Any solution for this @SureshBalaraman ? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: I register with the new app name and register in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge.
Now my problem solved.